# Merging two data frames with columns with certain patterns in strings

Tags: r, string, merge

(I have been stuck with this problem for past two days, So if it has an answer on SO please bear with me.)

I have two data frames A and B. I want to merge them on Name column. Suppose, A has two columns Name and Numbers. The Name column of A df has values ".tony.x.rds", ".tom.x.rds" and so on.

```
Name     Numbers
.tony.x.rds 15.6
.tom.x.rds 14.5
```

The B df has two columns Name and ChaR. The Name column of B has values "tony.x","tom.x" and so on.

```
Name  ChaR
tony.x   ENG
tom.x   US
```

The main element in column Name of both dfs is "tony', "tom" and so on.

> So, **".tony.x.rds"** is equal to **"tony.x"** and **".tom.x.rds"** is equal to **"tom.x"**.

I have tried gsub with various option leaving me with 'tony", "tom", and so on in column Name of both A and B data frames. But when I use

```
StoRe<-merge(A,B, all=T)
```

I ge all the rows of A and B  rather than single rows. That is, there are two rows for each "a", "b" and so on for with their respective values in Numbers and ChaR column. For example:

```
Name Numbers ChaR
tony    15.6    NA
tony    NULL    ENG
tom    14.5    NA
tom    NULL    US
```

It has been giving me splitting headache. I request you to help.

Comment: Not my downvote.  What is the actual condition on which you want to join the two dataframes?

Comment: I want to join on values in column Name. Actually column Names are Firm names and .a.x.rds  is equal to a.x

Comment: So would it be safe to say that `.a.x.rds` containing `a.x` is sufficient?

Comment: Yes it is suffcient. Having "a x" is also an option.

Comment: Please note I have given a and b as firm names which are generally words e.g. tony and tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution. I am not completely sure what you want to do with the 'x' in the strings, I have kept them in the linkage key, but by changing the `\\1\\2` to `\\1` you keep only the first letter.

```
a <- data.frame(
  Name = paste0(".", c("tony", "tom", "foo", "bar", "foobar"), ".x.rds"),
  Numbers = rnorm(5)
)

b <- data.frame(
  Name = paste0(c("tony", "tom", "bar", "foobar", "company"), ".x"),
  ChaR = LETTERS[11:15]
)

# String consists of 'point letter1 point letter2 point rds'; replace by
# 'letter1 letter2' 
a$Name_stand <- gsub("^\\.([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+)\\.rds$", "\\1\\2", a$Name)

# String consists of 'letter1 point letter2'; replace by 'letter1 letter2' 
b$Name_stand <- gsub("^([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+)$", "\\1\\2", b$Name)

result <- merge(a, b, all = TRUE, by = "Name_stand")
```

Output:

```
#> result
#  Name_stand        Name.x     Numbers    Name.y ChaR
#1       barx    .bar.x.rds  1.38072696     bar.x    M
#2   companyx          <NA>          NA company.x    O
#3    foobarx .foobar.x.rds -1.53076596  foobar.x    N
#4       foox    .foo.x.rds  1.40829287      <NA> <NA>
#5       tomx    .tom.x.rds -0.01204651     tom.x    L
#6      tonyx   .tony.x.rds  0.34159406    tony.x    K
```

Another, perhaps somewhat more robust (to variations of the strings such as 'tom.rds' and 'tom' which will still be linked; this can of course also be a disadvantage)/

```
# Remove the rds from a$Name
a$Name_stand <- gsub("rds$" , "", a$Name)
# Remove all non alpha numeric characters from the strings
a$Name_stand <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", a$Name_stand)
b$Name_stand <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", b$Name)

result2 <- merge(a, b, all = TRUE, by = "Name_stand")
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually a and b are firm names. So it could be .tony.ltd.rds and tony.ltd

Comment: @runjumpfly In that case you could use `[a-z]+` instead of `[a-z]`.

Comment: I have little experience of using gsub. So kindly see my edit and let me know how to use your solution

Comment: @runjumpfly I changed the example. I also added another solution.

Comment: An off note query: Is it ok to use full_join from plyr instead of merge?

Comment: @runjumpfly Of course, just use `full_join(a, b, by = c('Name_stand' = 'Name_stand'))`